# Weird `echo` behaviour

Tags: shell, echo

While doing some work, I came across this

```
$ echo [Login]
  g
$ echo [kilo]
  k
$ echo [gauke]
  e g k
$ echo [quasi-star]
  k m q
```

What is going on in the background that results in this output ? Output of `echo [quasi-star]` just lost it's mind giving letters that are not even in there.

**Note:** Yes I know I can get my output with `echo "[Login]"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without the quotes, the shell is doing pathname (glob) expansion on the character class `[]`, so presumably you have files named `e`, `g`, `k`, `m`, `q` in the current directory -- hence the result.

`echo` is basically just printing the result of pathname expansion, nothing more.

---

Let's take one example, `echo [quasi-star]`:

The result of expansion for `[quasi-star]` would be any single character from `quasijklmnopqrstar` (duplicates are kept intentionally). From shell's perspective, as there are no surrounding characters, so it would just match any single character filename on the current directory from the expansion.

Comment: If I type `echo [kilo]` on my machine, the output ist `[kilo]` and in this directory is no file with an `k`, `i` or `l` in it's filename.

Comment: @JohnGoofy Yes, that's expected (literal value), unless you have `nullglob`/`failglob` (assuming `bash`) set.

Comment: @heemayl But why there is only with `[kilo]` a literal echou output?